# Oracle Apex Session Timeout URL Ignored

Tags: oracle-apex

Apex Oracle 20.2
Database: 19c

shared components>security>session management>session timeout url

tried these URLS

```
f?p=106:timed-out:    name of the page
f?p=106:200:
f?p=106:200:&APP_SESSION.
```

When I use these URLs, they are ignored and the standard timeout page is shown.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Is your page 200 publically accessible? Not relevant passing APP_SESSION here as your existing session is no longer active.

I use this setting to pass a particular REQUEST value to the login page, to serve my UI.
[image: timeout setting]

See example at
http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2019/01/customising-oracle-apex-session-expiry.html

```
f?p=MY_APP:LOGIN:0:TIMEOUT
```

Comment: Made a dynamic action to test javascript: window.location.href = 'f?p=106:200:' that works.

Comment: used what is in single quotes for the timeout URL. Page 200 authentication: Page is Public. Still not working. What else should I check? Thanks

Comment: Like your link. WIll implement when I get the page to display. Thanks

Comment: tried the link with timeout t no help. Don't see anything in debug

Comment: went to timeout page, copied url, tried it on another machine. to verify that it really was publically accessible. It was. Also restarted DB APEX instance. No help.  Tried f?p=khn6:timed-out::TIMEOUT  for session idle timeout URL. Still ignored. Any ideas? How can I troubleshoot this? thanks

Comment: Have you tried passing 0 as the session ID?

Comment: tried this:   f?p=khn6:timed-out:0:TIMEOUT   Also tried single quotes around the string just to experiment. No help. Is there something somewhere else that might be causing the problem? If it works for everyone else who is at my rev, but not me, there has to be something different in my configuration somewhere. Is there anything at a higher level because I can't get it to work on a new test project either.

Comment: I can live with the apex timeout popup. Seems like getting the URL to work won't be easy.

Comment: It works for others? You're the only one with a problem regarding this configuration?

Comment: I am guessing it works for others since there are very few questions concnering the problem.